# Do bank statements need to be stamped for a Standard Visitor visa application for the UK?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

When applying for a Standard Visitor visa to the UK and providing documents as a sponsor, must the bank statements be stamped or can they be printed out from online?

Answer (score 3):

[Bank statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) are needed for a lot of different reasons and applying for a Standard Visitor Visa without including an indicative series of bank statements is *wildly* adventurous. You asked...

> When applying for a Standard Visitor Visa to the UK and providing
>   documents as a sponsor, must the bank statements be stamped or can
>   they be printed out from online?

You have three main options...

- Print them out from the net and have them stamped by a bank officer;
  or
- Send the paper statements that are received in the post; or
- Have a member of the UK Law Society submit copies (this option is not
  for individuals to do by themselves).

Sending photocopies or unattested print-outs is asking for trouble. The [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) is clear that all evidence should be originals. A sponsor's bank statements must follow the same rules as the applicant (this includes provenance of funds also).  Note: to help prevent identity theft, it is OK to blacken out any account numbers that appear on the statements and send them under separate cover (I used to do this as a matter of routine and never had a problem from it).