# Online Bank Statements for UK Visitor Visa -- Is it dangerous if they are not attested?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

*A related question is [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84424/do-bank-statements-need-to-be-stamped-for-a-standard-visitor-visa-application-fo), but I noticed it is from over a year ago and the conditions might have changed, and my question is a bit different than that one too.*

**Are print-outs of the bank statements generated inside the online banking portal of the bank accepted for UK visitor visa?**

I am attaching bank statements from two different accounts. For one of the accounts, I have the stamped version of the statements from the bank. However, from my other account (which happens to be in another far away country), I have absolutely no means to receive the physical stamped versions in such a short time. Therefore, will I be in trouble to give one set of bank statements stamped and the other set without any stamps?

**Would an affidavit by a local attorney at law help?** That is to say, if I ask a local attorney at law to write a statement that he has seen me log into my online banking account and print out the documents right from there in front of him, will this be acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

> Are print-outs of the bank statements generated inside the online banking portal of the bank accepted for UK visitor visa?

Yes, since now they are. Just got back from UK visa centre in Russia, and they **do not accept any of ORIGINAL** documents, only **COPIES** are accepted. Even then, they do not take the copies from you, just scan them and return to you back.

> Therefore, will I be in trouble to give one set of bank statements stamped and the other set without any stamps?

No, you will not. If you meant without a physical stamp. The printed stamp which the online bank usually stamp is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

> **Are print-outs of the bank statements generated inside the online banking portal of the bank accepted for UK visitor visa?**

I don't think so. Try your best to order originals. But I have not managed to find the proofs that online generated bank statements are not allowed to apply rather than vice-versa.

> **Therefore, will I be in trouble to give one set of bank statements stamped and the other set without any stamps?**

I would strongly advise you to order DHL for express delivery. It might be chipper than an affidavit by a local attorney at law.

> **Would an affidavit by a local attorney at law help?** That is to say, if I ask a local attorney at law to write a statement that he has seen me log into my online banking account and print out the documents right from there in front of him, will this be acceptable?

In the [Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) is written:

> > **Section 4: documents you should not send unless specifically requested**
> >
> > This page provides guidance on the types of documents that are not required to consider your application.
> >
> > - if you are applying as a family/group you do not need to provide
> >       multiple copies of the same documents
> > - bank statements or letters issued more than 1 year before the date of application
> > - driving licence
> > - photographs (other than passport photographs required in section 1)
> > - **notarial certificates**

So, I suppose, that it works for an affidavit by a local attorney at law also. Better to **order DHL** or **transfer your money from online account to the closest bank**.